# I can read data from android even when permissions are denied in firebase

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i have an android application connected to firestore. I have totally restricted database permissions, like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if (false);
    }
  }
}
```

The `crearDatos` function works perfectly, (it shows me an error when trying to create a data), but the function to read data, `EventChangeListener` reads the data even when the permissions are denied. Why can this be? Do you see in my code any reason why it can work like this?
On the other hand, I have a javascript application that also connects to the same firestore database, and it works perfectly. I mean that it denies me both reading and writing, so the problem must be in the android application.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText titulo,contenido;
    Button guardar,logout;
    FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    adapter a;
    ArrayList<Articulo> articulos=new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        titulo=findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        contenido=findViewById(R.id.contenido);
        guardar=findViewById(R.id.guardar);
        recycler=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        logout=findViewById(R.id.logout);

        guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                crearDatos();
            }
        });

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        //Query query= mFirestore.collection("Articulos");
        a=new adapter(articulos);
        recycler.setAdapter(a);
        EventChangeListener();
    }
    private void crearDatos()
    {
        String t=titulo.getText().toString();
        String c=contenido.getText().toString();
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("titulo",t);
        map.put("contenido",c);
        map.put("fecha", new Date().getTime());
        //mFirestore.collection("Articulos").document().set(map);
        mFirestore.collection("Articulos").add(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El articulo se creo correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hubo un error al crear el articulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void EventChangeListener()
    {
        mFirestore.collection("Articulos").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.e("Firestore Error",error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    Log.i("estoy aqui", "aqui estoy");
                    if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        articulos.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Articulo.class));
                    }
                        //a.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                a.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "even when the permissions are denied"?  Are you referring to security rules?  If so, you should update your post to show them, and explain why you are confused by the result.

Comment: i already edited the post

Comment: With those rules, if they are actually active on your project, I would expect all reads and writes to be rejects - nothing at all should work from your client app.

Comment: the write operation is rejected, but the read operation does not

Comment: Maybe you are getting data from the local cache.  Clear app storage and try again.

Comment: good! I was that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the case that a previous query cached some documents locally, those local documents might be used to serve a future request even if the security rules on the server have changed.

If you feel your app must respond immediately to security rules, you should prevent your app from using local events by specifying a "serve source" in your query in the query options parameter.